# how to set image, text size as screen resolution using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

how can I set image, text size as screen resolution using javascript in asp.net mvc project?

```
<body>
<div id="div1"><p>Font size</p>
      <img src="/Content/image.png" width="200" height="200"/>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to try this plugin in your project i hope it solve your problem

https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js